# Is there a way to access a variable from method parameter?

Tags: c#, arrays, point

I want to access x values from a Point from an array from a method parameter, but I get the error "'Point.x' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

I've tried to add and change the Point array and set it to public, but I got even more errors.

```
int findMeetingPlace(Point[] houseLocations, Point kakekHouse, int D)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    float xdisttoroot;
    float housedistx;
    float housedisty;
    float[] currenthousedist;
    int houseLlength = houseLocations.Length;

    for(i=0;i<=houseLlength;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=houseLlength;j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
                housedistx = houseLocations[i].x - houseLocations[j].x ;
        }
    }

    return (int)Math.Round(housedistx);
}
```

I expect the output to be housedistx int, but I get the said error at the 13th line.

Comment: What errors do you refer on ```but I got even more errors```?

Comment: There is a problem with the access-modifiers in your Point-class. Post the code of it if you want to avoid downvotes!

Comment: `Point.X` (capital `X`), `houseLocations[i].X`

Comment: What is the *original* problem? What do you try compute, please?

Comment: Post your `houseLocations` class. As other said, you are probably using `private` property.

Comment: @Matt `houseLocations` is an array of `Point`. Dmitry has identified the issue, I believe.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Then post `Point` class if you still have problems.

Comment: @Matt I think you may have mistaken me for the OP...

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use X (capital x), small x is private and cannot be accessed.

Comment: This is almost certainly the right answer. The `x` identifier is for the private field, aka `private TYPE x;`, and the `X` identifier is for the public property, aka `public TYPE X { get { return this.x; } set { this.x = value; } }`.